# Set up View Controllers in App Delegate Xcode 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

I wanted to know how to set up the app delegate in Xcode 5 since it's different than it was in previous versions. I want the generic view controller files (ViewController.h and .m) to be the files that control the rootViewController I set in my app delegate. Does this happen automatically or do you need to do something in the code? This is how I set up my appDelegate.m

```
    *(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary   *)launchOptions
{
    CGRect viewRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:viewRect];
    UIViewController  *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
    self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

If I wanted my rootView Controller to be a table view controller or something else, would I need to embed it in a basic VC first?

Comment: are you using storyboard?

Comment: Programmatically but doing it with storyboards is also something I'd like to know since Xcode 5 plops 'em in for you now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do it programmatically you can set it to be a `UITableViewController` since it is a subclass of `UIViewController`. If you want to use the already create `ViewController` just change the subclass in the `.h` file from `UIViewController` to `UITableViewController` and add the tableview delegates and datasources into the `.m`.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

UIViewController *mainViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewController"];

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.rootViewController = mainViewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

or if you want to just draw the view in the view controller create a class and do this

```
MyViewController  *viewController = [[MyViewController alloc]init];
self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
```

If you are wanting to set your root view via storyboards you can just check the __Is Initial view controller` option

[image]

Comment: But how does the appDelegate know that the already created ViewController files are the root if you do it programmatically? Say I wanted to delete those files and use another file, or had multiple instances of view controllers inheriting from UIViewController? Then the app delegate wouldn't know which ones to use.

Answer (score 0):

> If I wanted my rootView Controller to be a table view controller or something else, would I need to embed it in a basic VC first?

No.

You can set any UIViewController class to be the rootViewController. I am assuming you are building your viewController hierarchy in code, and you are not using InterfaceBuidler. Although also with Interface builder, you can use any viewContorller as the rootviewcontroller, either using storyboards or plain xibs.